# Python TkInter create a button to open a specific directory

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I want to create a button that opens the special directory like "C:\Users\", But as I searched, I did not find any code except the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("100x100")

def getFolderPath():
    filedialog.askdirectory()

btnFind = ttk.Button(gui, text="Open Folder",command=getFolderPath)
btnFind.grid(row=0,column=2)

gui.mainloop()
```

What is the correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os.startfile("C:\\Users")` to use the system file explorer to open the directory.

Comment: Open the window normally, not to select a directory!